# MongoDB performance - distinct with query on two fields with Index

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

We've a collection with two fields ( A and B ), both have an index.

Getting the disctinct on any of them is amazingly quick. But the actual query is a disctinct in A with a filter on the other field, B.

```
db.getCollection('Collection').distinct( "A" , { "B" : "b1" }  )
```

This is really, really slow as it's scanning the collection ( unfortunatly b1 is not filtering more than a 50% ). Is there a way to make this quicker in MongoDB ?

Answer (score 1):

According to this JIRA [ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19507) what you can do is just create a composite index like this:

```
db.collection.createIndex({ "B": 1, "A:" 1 })
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use compound index to solve this problem. As priority is important in [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#create-a-compound-index) based on you query, I recommend you to use this index {A:1, B:1}